# Using Comparator to compare a list of floats within an object

Tags: java

Hello I'm trying to sort a list of floats from the highest value first then to the lowest in an ArrayList.

CustomObject holds an object, that object has a value of float.

So far I'm doing this (failed, not doing anything).

```
Collections.sort(mNaturalResistanceBoxes, new Comparator < PercentageBox > () {
    public int compare(PercentageBox o1, PercentageBox o2) {
        return o1.mCountry.mNaturalResistance 
          < o2.mCountry.mNaturalResistance ? -1 : 
             o1.mCountry.mNaturalResistance > o2.mCountry.mNaturalResistance ? 1 : 0;
    }
});
```

Can anyone let me know where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: You do know that floats are not totally ordered, right? If you include NaN, it's not even a preorder.

Comment: Doesn't make sense, totally ordered?

Comment: @OllyDixon everything seems fine. Do you get any errors or they are not sorted? What happens

Comment: I don't get any errors, just nothing happens that's all.

Comment: So the list doesn't get modified?  It retains its original order?  Or is it getting sorted incorrectly?

Comment: It retains it's original order :-/

Comment: Are you looking at the result in a UI, or are you printing out the resulting array?  Maybe your UI is not updating?

Comment: Oh, I'll bet it's an order of operations that's getting you.  Write it out in a full-if-else and see what happens: if (o1.mCountry.mNaturalResistance < o2.mCountry.mNaturalResistance)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (o1.mCountry.mNaturalResistance > o2.mCountry.mNaturalResistance)
        {
            return 1
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }

Comment: Less and more readable code: `return Float.compare(o1.mCountry.mNaturalResistance, o2.mCountry.mNaturalResistance);` in your Comparator.

Comment: It's like it's being completely ignored but it's running I know that. Still doesn't work though.

Comment: @OllyDixon Have you tried debugging? Just set a breakpoint in your comparator.

Comment: Just to make sure: The input is actually unsorted w.r.t to the comparator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code works perfectly:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Snippet {

    static class Country {

        float mNaturalResistance;
    }

    static class PercentageBox {

        Country mCountry = new Country();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        List< PercentageBox > mNaturalResistanceBoxes = new ArrayList< Snippet.PercentageBox >();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            mNaturalResistanceBoxes.add(new PercentageBox());
        }

        mNaturalResistanceBoxes.get(0).mCountry.mNaturalResistance = 3.3f;
        mNaturalResistanceBoxes.get(1).mCountry.mNaturalResistance = 2.2f;
        mNaturalResistanceBoxes.get(2).mCountry.mNaturalResistance = 4.4f;
        mNaturalResistanceBoxes.get(3).mCountry.mNaturalResistance = 1.1f;

        Collections.sort(mNaturalResistanceBoxes, new Comparator< PercentageBox >() {

            @Override
            public int compare(final PercentageBox o1, final PercentageBox o2) {
                return o1.mCountry.mNaturalResistance < o2.mCountry.mNaturalResistance ? -1
                    : o1.mCountry.mNaturalResistance > o2.mCountry.mNaturalResistance ? 1 : 0;
            }
        });

        for (PercentageBox box : mNaturalResistanceBoxes) {
            System.out.println(box.mCountry.mNaturalResistance);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1.1
2.2
3.3
4.4
```